# Function to perform a logical NOT in a string

Tags: c, strings, parsing, math-expression-eval

I am using "tinyexpr", a cute library that can solve mathematical formulas in a string and I extended it such that it does logical operations with two operands as well.
However I wasn't sure how to handle the logical NOT as it is performed on a single operand, which is why I just created a small function that does just that outside of tinyexpr:

```
void handle_logical_not (char * expr)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; expr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(expr[i] == '!')
        {
            i++;

            if(expr[i] == '!')
            {
                handle_logical_not(&expr[i]); /* Recursively handle subexpressions */
            }
            if( (expr[i] >= '0' && expr[i] <= '9') || (expr[i] == '-' && (expr[i+1] >= '0' && expr[i+1] <= '9')) )
            {
                long int    val = 0;
                char*       end = NULL;
                size_t      len = 0;

                if(expr[i] == '0')  val = strtol(&expr[i], &end, 8);
                else                val = strtol(&expr[i], &end, 10);

                expr[i-1] = '0' + !val;

                len = (uintptr_t)&expr[MAX_EXPR] - (uintptr_t)end;

                memmove(&expr[i], end, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will normally pass a statically allocated string (an expression) to this function and it modifies it directly if it detects a logical NOT operation. For example `"!0+!0+!!0"`
and the function will replace it like that: `"1+1+0"`

Then you can pass the potentially modified string to tinyexpr for further evaluation.
Sadly, this obviously adds an additional complexity overhead.

---

**Remarks and Flaws:**

- As a bonus it adds a case for octal values.
- It does not skip whitespace characters

Comment: What is the expected result of `!(1 + 1)`?

Comment: @vnp `!(1)` would not be parsed at all. Parenthesizes are not considered and arithmetic is calculated afterwards in the application I am working on. I actually had a remark about that, but I removed it without consideration.

Answer (score 3):

**Declare when needed**

```
// size_t      len = 0;
// ...
// len = (uintptr_t)&expr[MAX_EXPR] - (uintptr_t)end;

size_t len = (uintptr_t)&expr[MAX_EXPR] - (uintptr_t)end;
```

**Scale task to problem size**

Consider the string may only be a few bytes, yet `MAX_EXPR` may be a million.  Rather than move lots of bytes, move what is needed.

```
size_t len = strlen(end) + 1;
```

(I may have an off-by-one oops here - worthy of more review.)

**Note: `errno` side-effect**

Using `strtol()`, `handle_logical_not()` *may* set `errno`.

**`+` is a sign too**

`expr[i] == '-'` does not account for `+` as a sign character.

**Octal -123?**

`if(expr[i] == '0')  val = strtol(&expr[i], &end, 8);` does not take into account an octal number may be signed.  `strtol()` and `"%o"` allow negative octal values.

**Pedantic: long strings**

String array indexing may exceed `INT_MAX`.  Use `size_t i`.

**Nice simply recursion use**

Even though a non-recursive solution is possible, this simply handles that issue.

**Save time**

Use an auto-formatter.

**Style**

Consider the terser:

```
            // long int    val = 0;
            long val = 0;
```

**Alternative**

Rather than `if( (expr[i] >= '0' && expr[i] <= '9') || ...`, consider calling `strtol(&expr[i], &end, 0)` and check for conversion success.

Bonus: accepts white-space, `+` sign and hexadecimal.

**Pedantic: -0**

For rare non-2's complement `char`, use `for(i = 0; ((unsigned char *)expr)[i] != '\0'; i++)` to not stop on a -0.

Likely irrelevant in next C2x version.